# Issue with absolute path of image_tag in Rails 3.2.15

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, mailer

I am having a lot of trouble specifying the absolute path of an image in my Rails mailer.  I've looked at a lot of examples of how to do this, and nothing has worked for me.

This is what I currently have in my development.rb file:

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => ENV['DEV_HOST_URL'] }

  /* Added the following 2 lines to attempt to get direct URL */
  config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://localhost:3000'
  config.action_mailer.asset_host = config.action_controller.asset_host

  config.assets.compress = false

  config.serve_static_assets = false

  config.assets.precompile << /(^[^_\/]|\/[^_])[^\/]*$/

  # Expands the lines which load the assets
  config.assets.debug = true
```

DEV_HOST_URL is defined in my environment variables:

```
DEV_HOST_URL: "0.0.0.0:3000"
```

I try to reference the image in my mailer layout file as follows:

```
<%= image_tag("logo.png", :class=>"logo_icon" ) %>
```

When I inspect the element in the resulting email, I get the following:

```
<img alt="logo" src="https://ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/LQ9_UbICRgtYrLdHWTYSCZzpvyyqEPa8zUTd1OjWkQZQCgnb5YdOQpbghkTKOqBF1miTwxYJYHNdriZh5de4XW161GU_8jvmNN2D3KU=s0-d-e1-ft#http://localhost:3000/assets/logo.png" style="width:50px;border:1px solid #ccc;min-height:20px;width:20px;border:none">
```

But if I go to the following link, I don't get a broken image:

```
http://localhost:3000/assets/logo.png
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've tested out my mailer with multiple images, and it seems like https links work ok.  Could it be that gmail does not accept not https links? or maybe just local images?  been trying to figure this out all day, so I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

This probably should have been obvious but wasn't to me at first – Gmail won't load local images.  When I pushed my code to production, I was able to see the correct images!